# LMDB will commit without closing connection?

Tags: ruby, lmdb

New to LMDB. Considering to use it via https://github.com/minad/lmdb on a PaaS as Redis replacement. But wondering what would happen to transactions if my Ruby program crashes and close() is not invoked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be rolled back. A properly written storage engine will not corrupt your data on power loss